# BLE Scan Results coming on UI thread

Tags: android

I am calling StartScan api of the class BluetoothLeScanner. The issue which I am observing is that the scancallback results are coming in the UI thread even if I call the startScan from a different thread. I used a different HandlerThread to call the StartScan but still the scan callback results are coming on the UI thread. Is there a way I can change that behavior and not have the events coming on UI thread but on a different thread?
 I can modify the OnScanResult api to post the event on a different thread. But I want the OnScanResult itself to not come on UI thread. Is there a way I can achieve this

Comment: What does your callback look like?

Comment: internal class MyScanCallBack : ScanCallback  
 {
  public override void OnScanResult (ScanCallbackType type, ScanResult result)
  {   

   using (var t = new Tracer (this.GetType ().Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod ().Name, result.Device.Name)) {
    processResult (result);
    
   }

  }

  public override void OnScanFailed (ScanFailure error)
  {
   BLECommProxyTrace.TraceError ("Scan failed"); 
  }

  public override void OnBatchScanResults (IList<ScanResult> scanResults)
  {
   foreach (ScanResult result in scanResults) {
    processResult (result);
   }
  }


 };